# using GRUB to boot a linux system on a different device?

Tags: grub2, ssd, raid

I bought a new SSD drive with the idea of running my Ubuntu system on it and leaving the other two SATA drives (which are configured in a RAID array) for storage only.

Ubuntu installed with no problem, but it turns out that my motherboard doesn't support AHCI and it doesn't see the SSD drive at all -- so I can't configure it to boot from the SSD.

Can I, theoretically, install GRUB on the SATA array and configure it so it boots the SSD?

When I run grub-mkconfig, it identifies the system installed in the SSD but it spits out the following error:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709421056
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709547008
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073708469760
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709289984
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709421056
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709547008
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073708469760
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709289984
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709421056
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709547008
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073708469760
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709289984
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709421056
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709547008
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073708469760
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709289984
Found Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sdc1
menuentry "Ubuntu, amb el Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (on /dev/sdc1)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 25ad7a52-d1b9-4d23-81b0-de24a593e8e5
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=25ad7a52-d1b9-4d23-81b0-de24a593e8e5 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
}
```

When I select the option for the sdc (the SSD drive) in GRUB it says:

```
error: no such device: cde9dac2-0db5-41f7-a35e-5462c02e3c35 
error: hd2 cannot get C/H/S values 
error: you need to load the kernel
```

Comment: While installing ubuntu on the external device, did you install the grub too on the external SSD?

Comment: It is an internal SSD. But yes, it should have installed itself on it too...

Comment: The grub won't install on the SSD on its own, you need to specify that when you partition the disk. Please confirm where you have installed the grub.

Comment: In that case, I'm not really sure. 
I'm running the old system in the SATA array now (let's call it sda)-- that one has GRUB, and its menu comes up at startup. However, it returns an error when I select the option for the other system in sdc

Comment: This is the error message I get when selecting the option for sdc in GRUB menu:

error: no such device: cde9dac2-0db5-41f7-a35e-5462c02e3c35
error: hd2 cannot get C/H/S values
error: you need to load the kernel first